# Implementations of the `GRU` cell is different from the descriptions

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, gru

I need to put `GRU` cell for inference on certain hardware. And as I just found, definitions, available on Internet from multiple sources, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_recurrent_unit, is not agree with cell implementations on both `pytorch` (https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html) and `tensorflow`, namely
[image]
[image: foo]
**vs**
[image: bar]

In former case, gate applyed before matrix multiplication, in latter - after.
Me pretty surprized. And can't find any discussion about the issue. `GRU` already have some variants (see wikipedia), but they can be covered by some maximal implementation, while here we have incompatible versions. To make inference work, I have to make pipeline exactly as on training. Is this all right, so I just must to look cerefully for each possible source of monolithic cell, or is there one right implementation? What is canonical `GRU` cell for measurments?